# Auto Center Transform not working

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effects

I am having real trouble getting a simple rotate effect to work properly. I want to apply a simple rotation effect on a border container. The rotation plays ok, but it does not rotate around its centre, but around its top left corner x/y.

I have read that by setting the autoCenterTransform to true, this will automatically make this happen, however it is not, it is still rotating around top left corner?

Here is my component code...

```
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   width="50"
                   height="50">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Rotate id="rotateMinus60"
                  target="{this}"
                  autoCenterTransform="true"
                  angleTo="-60">
        </s:Rotate>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function rotateObject():void{
                rotateMinus60.play();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

I am calling the 'rotateObject' function from somewhere else, but that shouldn't matter, perhaps I have missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the answer, it was the way I was positioning my component inside a parent container, using top and bottom values in a canvas instead of x and y values. As soon as I changed to using x and y values instead, the rotation played around a central point.